# Подскажите какие свойства нужно добавить в классы, чтобы настроить отношения между таблицами

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework-core

У меня есть 4 таблицы в бд вакансии, работники, скилы и отделы. Когда я добавляю работника, то я могу выбрать ему несколько скилов, если я выбираю несколько скилов, но получаю ошибку SqlException: Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Skills' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF, я так понимаю мне нужно создать правильные отношения между таблицами. ну то есть добавить в таблицу Employee поля public Skill Skill и public int SkillId, что-то в этом роде, но я в этом не очень разбираюсь, подскажите как нужно мне сделать, чтобы когда я добавлял работника с двумя или больше скилами и в табилце Employee была ссылка на эти скилы или как правильнее сделать подскажите, как мне сохранять работника, чтобы у него было несколько скилов, притом 2 или 3 или 5, это уже должно выясняться автоматически, сколько выберешь в программе.

```
public class Employee
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string SecondName { get; set; }
    public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
    public decimal Salary { get; set; }
    public bool Bonus { get; set; }
    public List<Skill> Skills { get; set; }

    public Employee(string name, string secondName, DateTime birth, decimal salary, bool bonus, List<Skill> skills)
    {
        Name = name;
        SecondName = secondName;
        BirthDate = birth;
        Salary = salary;
        Bonus = bonus;
        Skills = skills;
    }
    public Employee() { }
}

public class Skill
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Skill() { }
}

    private void btnHireEmp_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var form = new HireEmploee();
        if (form.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            db.Employees.Add(form.Employee);
            db.SaveChanges();
            MessageBox.Show(form.Employee.Name + ": was hired");
        }

        UpdateEmp();
    }
```

Comment: core............

Comment: https://metanit.com/sharp/entityframeworkcore/3.5.php

Comment: Либо, если Вам удобней разрабатывать сначала БД, то можете разработать БД в дизайнере, например в [SQL Server Management Studio](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms), а затем сгенерировать код для выбранной БД с помощью [Scaffold-DbContext](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/powershell#scaffold-dbcontext). В этом случае весь необходимый код сгенерируется автоматически и на мой взгляд, послужит неплохим "быстрым стартом".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При настраивании отношений между моделями следует учитывать тот фактор что у зависимой сущности должен быть так званый внешний ключ. Это такое свойство в котором хранится первичный ключ главной сущности. Также название этого поля должно начинаться з названия класса главной сущности + Id. Например, название класса главной сущности Employee, поэтому в классе Skill должно быть свойство EmployeeId, с тем же типом что и первичный ключ у Employee(В вашем случае int).
Также у обеих сущностей должно быть так званое навигационное свойство. Это поле с типом противоположной сущности для получения данных другой сущности. Звучит всё сложно но давайте разберёмся на вашем примере.
В вашем случае Employee - главная сущность а Skill - зависимая. Также, так как один работник может иметь несколько скилов то отношение будет один ко многим. В классе Employee у вас всё верно, так как имеется навигационное свойство Skills, а вот в классе Skill отсутствует навигационное свойство указывающее на работника и внешний ключ также указывающий на него. Поэтому следует изменить класс Skill на подобие следующего примера:

```
public class Skill
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Skill { get; set; }

    public Employee Employee { get; set; } // навигационное свойство
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; } // внешний ключ
}
```

Также рекомендуется настроить отношение между моделями с помощью FluentAPI. Для этого добавьте следующий метод в класс контекста данных:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Employee>()
            .HasMany(p => p.Skills)
            .WithOne(p => p.Employee)
            .HasForeignKey<Skill>(p => p.EmployeeId);
    }
```

Также учитывайте что отношение между моделями ведёт к каскадному удалению. Это значит что при удалении главной сущности удалятся также и все зависимые. В вашем случае при удалении работника удалятся также и все скилы что были к нему привязаны. Также в вашем случае рекомендую использовать отношение многое к многим так как один работник может иметь несколько скилов и несколько работников могут иметь один и тот самый скил. Подробнее об отношении многое ко многом [тут](https://metanit.com/sharp/entityframeworkcore/3.6.php). Также прочтите вот [эту](https://metanit.com/sharp/entityframeworkcore/3.2.php) статью об каскадном удалении, и [эту](https://metanit.com/sharp/entityframeworkcore/3.3.php) статью об загрузке связных данных. Надеюсь что помог вам. Удачи.